# Getting width and height of a resized image in php

Tags: php, image, resize

I have an image uploader, that creates many sizes of the uploaded image :

```
// Variables
$alpha = $_GET['a'];
$method = $_GET['m'];
$extension = $_GET['e'];

// Configuration
$methods = array
(
'original'  =>  true,
'icon'      =>  array(48, 48),
'small'     =>  array(110, 80),
'medium'    =>  array(360, 0),
'square'    =>  array(186, 186)
);
```

And here is the output for the image :

```
// Output
public function output($method)
{
    echo '<img src="'.WEB.$method.'/'.$this->alpha().'.'.$this->extension.'" width="" height="" alt="'.stripslashes($this->title).'" title="'.stripslashes($this->title).'"/>';
}
```

I would like to fill the width and the height of the image, using the $methods arrays, I tried this :

```
$r_width = $methods[$method][0];
$r_height = $methods[$method][1];

(...)  width="'.$this->r_width.'" height="'.$this->r_height.'"  (...)
```

But it doesn't display anything. What's wrong ?

If it can help, here is the resizer.php ( http://pastebin.com/gpP4mWSL ), and the image class ( http://pastebin.com/etJARPeY )

Edit : On the view page, here is how I display the image :

```
<a href="<?php echo WEB.$image->alpha(); ?>/"><?php $image->output('small'); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting, like you have to, the image class parameters r_width and r_height ?

You should have in your code something like that :

```
<?php
$image = new Image();
(...)
$image->r_width = $r_width;
$image->r_height = $r_height;
(...)
$image->output($method);
?>
```

Comment: I tried `width="'.$r_width.'" height="'.$r_height.'"` but not returning anything either

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong image class link, now it's updated : http://pastebin.com/etJARPeY

Comment: It doesn't display anything because you're never setting an Image object and you're never calling any method of that class (as Image:output).
You're calling a function named output() but it's not the same.

Comment: But the image display right, the extension, src, method etc... all works fine, it's just the height and width that doesn't display

Comment: Are you doing $image->r_width = $r_width; and $image->r_height = $r_height; somewhere in your code ?

Comment: No, everything I have is on those 2 php pages, I'll try that. Should it be in the class page or resizer page ?

Comment: It's on a view page (I'm using a MVC), it displays like this : `<a href="<?php echo WEB.$image->alpha(); ?>/"><?php $image->output('small'); ?></a>`

Comment: So, where are you doing $image = new Image(); ?
You have to find it, and to put the lines I wrote in the answer under it.

Comment: Returns `Unknown column 'r_width' in 'field list'`

Comment: Yes, you have to give the variables to each function so they'll be able to use them.

Comment: Actually, it's because `$this->extension` or `$this->title` comes from the Database, and I don't want the width and height from the DB, but simply from the method array. It should be simple, don't know what I missed...

Comment: Though this is pretty simple, you should understand what the problem is, you can't access your variables from everywhere, you have to give them to your functions. Inform yourself on variables scope in php.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can use this function to get the image height and width [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: Why I pressed on using this is to get a precise value for height and width. Unsure about the algorithm you are using to resize images, but what i feel is that images should maintain the height and width ratios while resizing, otherwise they look contorted/distorted/elongated. It's a thing that's taken care of by almost all popular JQuery based image resize plugins.